# iPhone :remoteioplayer   how to know that the song has finished playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

in iPhone App I am playing song with remoteioplayer.
while playing a song how to know that the  song has finished playing. I want set  some event on that poing?

Comment: Possible dupe - see [avaudioplayer-playing-multiple-audio-files-in-sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621182/avaudioplayer-playing-multiple-audio-files-in-sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Implement **AVAudioPlayerDelegate**.

It has following delegate method from which you can know song has finished playing.

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                        successfully: (BOOL) flag {
    NSLog(@"Finished");
}
```

You can refer detailed [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying%3asuccessfully%3a).

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for replay i would like to know same thing for remoteioplayer also

Answer (score 0):

Implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate methods in your class. The method

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

will be fired when the AVAudioPlayer stops playback.

More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html)